# How to use BigQuery API from elixir code

Tags: google-bigquery, elixir, google-cloud-platform

How to use BigQuery from elixir code?

I would like to use Big Query web API from elixir code. Although there is no elixir client SDK in [SDK libraries page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries)

I will use BigQuery API with service account. For using service account, I have to exec "JWT encode"...

Do you know suitable elixir library for using BigQuery API?

Comment: In general if you can't find a pre-built library for some web api the advice is to look for a REST interface and use that.  It's pretty easy to do from Elixir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery implements a traditional REST API. If no one has implemented it before, it should be straightforward to create one using a REST library.

REST for elixir:

- https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#rest-and-api

You'll need to authenticate too, OAUTH2 for elixir:

- https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#authentication

Comment: Thank you.
I understand. I will try to use described library.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a library, but the following repo has some example code for some basic usages on BigQuery (It was just an experiment and pretty much immature, but I'm hoping that it's better than nothing..)

https://github.com/parroty/big_query

Comment: Thank you! That has become a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but looks like this exists now: https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api/tree/main/clients/big_query/

Writing this for folks who come here years later (like I did).